# How should I export/import argparse defaults to config file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, argparse

I am currently exporting it to a JSON, via

```
arg = parser.parse_args()
param = vars(arg)
with open('config.txt') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(param), indent=4)
```

and then read it via https://github.com/patarapolw/duendecat/blob/32cc903377d0aa8033e2778592a230712c623c11/main.py#L33

So, that I can edit default values via `config.txt`.

However, I cannot add comments to lines in JSON, making it less readable...

Comment: [Figura](https://figura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might be useful here.

Comment: The answer may be [YAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), but I haven't tested it yet.